# Making an adjustable resistance

Tags: potentiometer, ldr

In my latest circuit, I needed an adjustable resistance to adjust the ratio of a nearby ldr. It looks roughly like this: (btw, I'm not so sure that this schematic is correct. Feel free to fix it :)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fO5i2T.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is used in conjunction with an arduino. The ground and 5V come from it, and the output goes to an analog input.

As you can see, I used a potentiometer as an adjustable resistance. But it sounds like overkill, since a potentiometer has 2 inputs, and I use only one.

Something seems wrong to me in this.

1. Is this the right way to calibrate an ldr ?
2. Is it right to use a potentiometer as a variable resistance ?

Comment: We need to see more of your circuit to tell you if you're calibrating the LDR properly. What is the LDR used for?

Comment: Actually this part of the circuit is isolated from any other component (except via 5v & ground). Other than that, you can find LEDs and a shift register, but I guess they do not interact much. Or do they ? The ldr is used only as a light sensor... is there more to it ?

Comment: I mean, what is the LDR's purpose? Are you sensing ambient light level? Are you changing the light level applied to the LDR with an LED to get a voltage-controlled resistor? Is it just there to decorate the diagram?

Comment: Oh actually the circuit is a kind of "light meter". It lights up LEDs according to the ambient light.

Comment: Okay, edited my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the pot like this is fine. Usually, when connecting a potentiometer as a variable resistor, you connect the unused pin to the wiper. Makes the circuit diagram look a bit cleaner, and in audio circuits keeps the pot from making scratchy noises while it's being turned.

For sensing ambient light level, this calibration arrangement should be fine.

Also, just a few schematic-drawing tips: Signals/information should tend to flow from left to right, while voltages should tend to go from top to bottom. Like so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhQIp5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Nice schematic example. I'm a little puzzled however. In my case, I have "ground" instead of a negative. I guess it's exactly the same, but should I always draw both negative and ground in my schematics ?

Comment: Electric current flows a bit like a conveyor belt. You have motors (voltage sources) pushing the conveyor belt through resistances (resistors); the speed of the belt (current) is determined by the force the motors apply divided by the friction of the belt. A low force can produce a high speed if the friction is low, and a high force could produce a low speed if the friction is very high. The belt must *always* form a loop. Electrical current, like the belt, always needs a way to get back.

Comment: "Ground" is just a simplification for schematics. Everything that you say is connected to "ground" is connected to everything else you say is connected to "ground"; thus ground serves as a return path for the current, but one you can use without drawing really long wires.